# spell checker for java fx

Tags: javafx, spell-checking

We have a desktop application built on java FX technology. Here we want to have spell checking feature for the text areas.

Could anyone please help us whether there are any spell checkers available in market for the GUI built on java FX. I searched over the net and found all spell checkers support GUI built on Swings and AWT

Thanks,
Eshwari

Comment: I certainly haven't found any when I've looked. The best solution I've seen so far is to just embed a normal JTextArea inside a SwingNode and use that - admittedly not JavaFX, but does the job.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289785/9278333